# Magento2: How can update the product price using before plugin

Tags: magento2, product, price, plugin

I want to update the product price using plugin and I tried the afterGetPrice() plugin its working fine in normal case but showing wrong price calculation when catalog price rule applied, I want to apply catalog price rule before the plugin execution.
I tired the below code :

**di.xml :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Product.php**

```
public function afterGetPrice($product, $proceed) : float
    {
        return $proceed+111.55;
    }
```

I want to apply catalog price rule before the plugin execution.

Comment: in frontend or backend?

Comment: Can you talk us through the outcome you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to update the price on frontend via some condition

Comment: post your `di.xml` and `module.xml`, also mention the file for this code `afterGetPrice()` you have mentioned.

Comment: @MohitRane question edited

Comment: you can remove `disabled="false"` this by default plugin is active

Comment: @MohitRane, its already working fine only thing is that its showing wrong calculation in case of catalog price rule applied

Comment: which price rule you have set?

Comment: which page you want to change price ?

Comment: set any discount fixed or percentage

Comment: @RkRathod Product list and details

Comment: used "getValue" function of "Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice " File

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @MagentoDev you can try this - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-change-product-price-with-plugin-magento-2.html

Comment: find any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

You should use **afterGetFinalPrice** instead of **afterGetPrice**, that way all calculations of prices will be done.